# Pine Script to build logic based volumes logic at low timeframe and use sum at high level

Tags: pine-script

I need help in creating ping script (V5) in tradingview based on following logic.
Ex
On 1 minute TF, if close is higher than previous close , classify the volume as positive. Even when TF is changed (to let's say 1 hour) , this calculation should run on 1 min TF and aggregate on any higher TF.
To perform this calculation, I tried defining security like *volume_=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', volume)* but using condition as *plusvolume = if (((high_-low_)*.75)>(close1_-close_)and close_>close1_)
volume_
else
0*
but its not working unfortunately.
Help with right method/syntax to achieve this .
Regards
G1

Comment: `security` function was designed to request data of a timeframe higher than the current chart timeframe. It is not recommended to request data of a timeframe lower that the current chart timeframe. Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#requesting-data-of-a-lower-timeframe).

Comment: You are right @vitruvius . It'll not work here. What would be the right way in such case then